# Why do new data not appear in the endpoint after taking the build?

Tags: firebase, endpoint, next.js14

I'm using Next.js 14. I'm trying to create an endpoint.
Until I take a build, the endpoint gives the correct result. But after taking the build, I can't see the new data added to the database in the endpoint

```
// This is the function that fetches data from Firebase.
export const getNames = async (): Promise<StateType<Name[]>> => {
    try {
        const usersCollection = collection(db, "names");
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usersCollection);
        const users = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Name);

        return {loading: false, data: users, error: null};
    } catch (error) {
        const e = new Error("An issue accorded while getting users from database");
        return {loading: false, data: null, error: e};
    }
};
```

I use the above function to fetch data from Firebase both in the src/app/api/route.ts file and in the src/app/page.tsx file.

```
//src/app/api/route.ts
export async function GET() {
     const response = await getNames();
     return NextResponse.json(response);
}
```

my home page

```
//src/app/page.tsx
export default function Home() {

const [result, setResult] = useState<Name[]>([])

React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => await getNames()

    fetchData().then((result) => {
        if (result.data)
        setResult(result.data)
    })
}, [])


return (
    <main className={"relative w-full"}>
        <h1 className={"text-3xl font-bold text-center"}>Names</h1>
        <div className={"grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4"}>
            {result.map((name: { name: string }) => (
                <div key={name.name} className={"bg-gray-100 p-4 rounded-md"}>
                    <h2 className={"text-xl font-bold"}>{name.name}</h2>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </main>
  )}
```

There's no problem on the Home page; the data is coming through properly. However, after taking the build, new data does not come through the endpoint I created.

Where am I making a mistake?